# GORM: mapping large text fields database agnostically

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a Grails application that will run against either a SQL Server or Oracle backend. I am using GORM as an ORM.

I want to map a large text field in a way that supports both database types. In my Grails domain class I have something like:

```
class Note {
    String content

    static constraints = {
        content nullable: false, blank: false
    }
}
```

I then declare database tables that look like this:

```
-- oracle
CREATE TABLE NOTE 
(
    id NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,
    version NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,
    content CLOB NOT NULL
);

-- SQL Server
CREATE TABLE NOTE 
(
    id NUMERIC(19, 0) NOT NULL,
    version NUMERIC(19, 0) NOT NULL,
    content NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);
```

GORM is running in `validate` mode on startup, and I can't find a combination of Oracle and SQL Server data types and GORM mappings that allow the storage or large text fields without GORM failing to start correctly.

I have tried:

- setting the type to `text` in `mappings`, but this doesn't seem to work. Oracle complains about expecting the `content` field to be of type `long`, and SQL Server wants a type of `text` in these circumstances.
- setting the `type` to `clob`, which passes schema validation but then doesn't allow me to set the field as a string value - GORM expects data of type `CLOB`.

How should I configure my database definitions and GORM to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hackish as it is, a solution eventually emerged: by querying the Grails configuration at startup time, you can select an appropriate data type.

```
class Note {

    String content

    static constraints = {
        content nullable: false, blank: false
    }

    static mappings = {
        content sqlType: DbSupport.bigStringType
    }
}

class DbSupport {

    static def getBigStringType() {

        // examine which hibernate dialect is selected, and pick
        // an appropriate type mapping for that database type:
        def dialect = ApplicationHolder.application.config.dataSource.dialect
        switch (dialect) {

            case "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect":
                return "nvarchar"
                break

            case "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect":
                return "clob"
                break
        }

    }
}
```