# Mapping Clob type in grails domain class with postgresql text type

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I am using the code is working for Derby, MySQL, Oracle but it's throwing error while using with PostgreSQL I'm getting error **org.hibernet.exception.DataException could not execute the query**.

I'm getting a solution to map text with String.
But nowhere solution is for map text with Clob in domain class.

```
class Ticket {
    String id
    String name
    String customerId
    int severity
    Clob description
    String component
    Clob screenshot

    static mapping = {
        version false
        table 'MY_TICKET'
        id generator: 'assigned'
        columns {
            id column: 'TICKET_ID'
            customerId column: 'CUSTOMER_ID'
        }
    }

    static constraints = {
        id bindable: true
    }   
}
```

Comment: I followed the approach 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420081/gorm-mapping-large-text-fields-database-agnostically?rq=1     so I'm able to see data.

One place i'm making a call Ticket.get(id) which internally calling hibernate reflection for get calls and i'm getting the error saying org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Could not set Could not set field value [DESCRIPTION] value by reflection class Ticket.description.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Clob type to String Type

```
class Ticket {
    String id
    String name
    String customerId
    int severity
    String description
    String component
    String screenshot

    static mapping = {
        version false
        table 'MY_TICKET'
        id generator: 'assigned'
        columns {
            id column: 'TICKET_ID'
            customerId column: 'CUSTOMER_ID'
        }
    }

    static constraints = {
        id bindable: true
    }  

     component sqltype:'text'
     screenshot sqltype:'text'
}
```

When we need to use a clob type in our mapping we always model it as a String with mapping type: 'text'.

Comment: Thanks, @Ajay it works for me.

I saw sqltype and type what actually difference between these.